# Getting numbers after decimal in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a color picker, and the hue values returned are numbers between zero and 1.
To create variations on the hue, I add .2 for 20%, .8 for 80% etc.

How can I keep the numbers going around the circle, so that when the number goes above 1, it subtracts the 1.  How can I make this number into this number:
1.73540012511 ---> .7354

I tried using a "cents" javascript, (http://www.irt.org/script/6.htm) but this returned values greater than 1:
http://jsfiddle.net/Se9Dn/

I can't use Math.min, because I want 1.2 to become .2 (not to have the colors all become red when they hit 1).

Thanks. :)

---

**Edit:**
Confirming solution, with rounding added. Assuming you have an HSL color (Hue, Saturation, Luminosity) returned from Farbtastic and want to adjust Hue mathematically:

```
hslcolor  = (.73802938, .59832908, .948987);
colorStep = .2;
newcolor[0] = Math.round ( ((1*colorStep +hslcolor[0])%1)*10000 ) /10000;
```

Watch out those parenthesis are very tricky in there.

Comment: If it's greater than 1 just subtract 1 ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the modulo operator `%` ([MDN docu](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#.C2.A0.25_%28Modulus%29)).

So for adding, e.g., `0.8`:

```
result = (result + 0.8) % 1;
```

**EDIT**

The modulo operator of JavaScript is actually more of a remainder operator.

Citing the [ECMAScript spec Section 5.2](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-5.2):

> The notation “x modulo y” (y must be finite and nonzero) computes a value k of the same sign as y (or zero) such that abs(k) < abs(y) and x−k = q × y for some integer q.

Comment: No.  That will always return an integer remainder, which is not at all what's requested here.

Comment: Whoa, you're right ... I don't understand how that makes sense, but as I noted a moment ago I haven't had a drop of coffee this morning so parts of my brain aren't working.

Comment: The code example in the answer will return NaN, since no value was set when the variable is declared above and used on the same line.

Comment: @Sirko yes I guess my concept of `%` got stuck shortly after I learned C 30 years ago :-)

Answer (score 1):

You just subtract the integer:

```
function cent(amount) { return (+amount) - Math.floor(+amount); }
```

If the number can be negative, then the it depends on the semantics you want. I'll leave that as an exercise :-)